# RX Objservable - .of() method does not exist from angular 2 beta

Tags: typescript, angular

So I'm quite new to Angular 2 and I have a question that I can't seem to find anywhere else online.

I'm trying to have some protected routes in my app.
I'm following some examples online. But I guess these example are based on Angular 2 beta.

There is a return function that has Observable.of(somevalue). This .of() method doesn't exist in RC i believe.

How can I make this work?

I will appreciate any help or thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import:

```
import 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

or to import all at once

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```